# Google speech v2: 'Expected resource location to be global, but found europe-west4 in resource name.',

Tags: location, google-speech-api

I created a Google Cloud Speech v2 recognizer via the front end of the web google cloud console. The Recognizer service is located in **europe-west4**, because I need the **chirp** model.
The problem comes when i try to get the recognizer via the Node.js client library.

`` client.getRecognizer({ name: `projects/${project}/locations/europe-west4/recognizers/my-first-chirp` }) `` 
The error is:

`Google speech v2: 'Expected resource location to be global, but found europe-west4 in resource name.',`

When i try to create a different recognizer in **europe-west4** i get the same error, but when creating in "**global**" location there is no problem. The issue is that the model and language I need are not supported in "**global**".

When I tried to find my recognizer in "**global**" with `.getRecognizer` I got an error sayign there isn't such recognizer (as expected, because it is not in global).

I there a way to use google's node library with europe-west4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the client you need to set the region in the URL:

For Javascript/Typescript:

```js
this.client = new v2.SpeechClient({
    apiEndpoint: `europe-west4-speech.googleapis.com`,
});
```

For Python

```py
client_options_var = client_options.ClientOptions(
    api_endpoint="europe-west4-speech.googleapis.com"
)
    client = SpeechClient(client_options=client_options_var)
```

Beware the "-speech" part `region + "-speech.googleapis.com"`

Comment: Thank you, this worked!


A little after I posted the question i saw in the library and the documentation mentions of passing the apiEndpoint argument in the constructor and tried it like this:
```const client = new v2.SpeechClient({ apiEndpoint: 'europe-west4' })```
This resultet in no error, but also the program freezes on awaiting of the .batchRecognize() promise.